# Scraping reports from a website using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download reports from a companies website, https://www.investorab.com/investors-media/reports-presentations/. In the end, I would like to download all the available reports.

I have next to none experience in webscraping, so I have some trouble defining the correct search pattern. Previously I have needed to take out all links containing pdfs, i.e. I could use soup.select('div[id="id-name"] a[data-type="PDF"]'). But for this website, there is not listed a datatype for the links. How do I select all links under "Report and presentations"? Here is what I have tried, but it returns an empty list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.investorab.com/investors-media/reports-presentations/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

# Select all reports, publication_dates
reports = soup.select('div[class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-events-archive i18n-en"] a[href]')
pub_dates = soup.select('div[class="html not-front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-events-archive i18n-en"] div[class="field-content"]')
```

I would also like to select all publications date, but also ends up with an empty list. Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do is iterate through the pages, or what I did was just iterate through the year parameter. Once you get the list for the year, get the link of each report, then within each link, find the pdf link. You'll then use that pdf link to write to file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

# Gets all the links
linkList = []
url = 'https://vp053.alertir.com/v3/en/events-archive?'
for year in range(1917,2021):

    query = 'type%5B%5D=report&type%5B%5D=annual_report&type%5B%5D=cmd&type%5B%5D=misc&year%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=' + str(year)

    response = requests.get(url + query )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    linkList += [link['href'] for link in links if 'v3' in link['href']]
    print ('Gathered links for year %s.' %year)

# Go to each link and get the pdsf within them
print ('Downloading PDFs...')
for link in linkList:
    url = 'https://vp053.alertir.com' + link
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    for pdflink in soup.select("a[href$='.pdf']"):
        folder_location = 'C:/test/pdfDownloads/'
        if not os.path.exists(folder_location):
            os.mkdir(folder_location)

        try:
            filename = os.path.join(folder_location,pdflink['href'].split('/')[-1])
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(requests.get('https://vp053.alertir.com' + pdflink['href']).content)
                print ('Saved: %s' %pdflink['href'].split('/')[-1])
        except Exception as ex:
             print('%s not saved. %s' %(pdflink['href'],ex))
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers my variation nicely. It  is much appreciated.